# Wait terraform till one loop is executed

Tags: terraform, azure-rm-template, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create multiple database using terraform script and arm templates. Basically i am calling arm templates from terraform.

Here i want to create multiple database by making the count wait till 1 is created and then execute the 2nd loop.

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "db" {
  count                             = length(local.env.other_database_to_be_created)
  name          = "sql-uppers-digital-${local.env.other_database_to_be_created[count.index]}"
  resource_group_name   = local.env.rg_name
  template_body = file("${path.module}/sqldbserver.json")

  parameters        = {
    sqlServerName       = local.env.sqlServerName
    location = local.env.location
    sqlDbName = local.env.other_database_to_be_created[count.index]
    sqlDbCollation      = local.env.sqlDbCollation
    sqlDbEdition = local.env.sqlDbEdition
    sqlDbRequestedServiceObjectiveName= local.env.sqlDbRequestedServiceObjectiveName
    sqlServerAdminLogin         = local.env.sqlServerAdminLogin
    sqlServerAdminLoginPassword = local.env.sqlServerAdminLoginPassword
    }

  deployment_mode   = "Incremental"

timeouts {
    create = "20m"
  }
  depends_on                        = [azurerm_template_deployment.sqlserver]
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What's wrong with the code? Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin Actually i am creating using arm templates and this arm templates are called from terraform. So i wanted it to wait till the first loop is completed and then create the second database. My main aim is to create multiple database using arm templates but it should be called from terraform

Comment: Why wouldn't you want them to all be created in parallel? You can also set the [`-parallelism`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/apply.html#parallelism-n) flag to just do one thing at a time if you wanted that.

Answer (score 0):

In Terraform's model, all instances of a particular resource are acted on concurrently. The exact execution details can vary depending on what else Terraform is working on, because there is a limit on concurrency imposed for reasons of resource usage, but you should write your configuration under the assumption that all instances of a particular resource are independent from one another and can be created in any order and possibly created at the same time.

If you have one object that depends on another then you must write them as two separate `resource` blocks, even if they have the same resource type. You can then use references from one to the other to show Terraform that there's a dependency relationship between them and thus that one must be created before the other.